# socketchannel reconnect after conection failed

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, selector, channel

Hi I have a thread that's the run implementation methode,this thread (client side) manage communication over my server, I want to know how to manage in case it fails due to a connection issue and how to reconnect. what I did is as you see bellow I add a listener that trigger when connection fails and I just start the thread again, the isue or the spooky part is only read options is rised after reconnect and I can t write anything via socket probably is becouse bad release of socket, any help?  Thanks

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        selector = Selector.open();

        mSocketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        mSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        mSocketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mIpAddress, mPort));



        while(!mSocketChannel.finishConnect());

        mSocketChannel.register(selector,
                SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);


        while (!stop) {

            int readyChannels = selector.select();

            if (readyChannels == 0)
                continue;

            //Log.i("selected","selected channels: "+readyChannels);
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();


            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                SelectionKey selectedKey = keyIterator.next();

                keyIterator.remove();

                if(!selectedKey.isValid()){
                    continue;
                }


                if (selectedKey.isAcceptable()) {

                } else if (selectedKey.isConnectable()) {

                } else if (selectedKey.isReadable()) {
                    read(selectedKey);

                } else if (selectedKey.isWritable()) {
                    write(selectedKey);
                }



            }


        }

        mSocketChannel.close();
        selector.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            mSocketChannel.close();
            selector.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mListener!=null)
            mListener.onScocketClosed();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible, but you shouldn't normally register for OP_WRITE: you should just write, and register for OP_WRITE only while the socket send buffer is full, i.e. when you get a zero return from the write() method.

Comment: you should register both.I think the issue is a deadlock but it's beyond this peace of code.